# How I can return the result of query in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have function in PostgreSQL, when I want to return the results I got error :

```
    ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
    HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
```

Here is summary my function ( it's too long to copy/paste all of code here)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "schema"."test"(IN Id int8,)

 RETURNS TABLE("Id" uuid, "SiteId" uuid, "Domain" varchar,
 "JumpCost" numeric, "CPMCost" numeric, "PaymentModel" int8, "ComputedEpm" numeric,
 "ClickedCampaignId" int8, "MainRubricId" int8, "ShowSlider" bool,
 "ShowGoods" bool, "ShowTeaser" bool, "BidLimitCoeff" numeric,
 "RtbActiveSiteStatByBannerId" int8, "ShowType" int8, "MinAge" int8) AS

$BODY$

DECLARE
     rtbCampaignEpmCoeff NUMERIC(18,6);
     maxRubricShows int;   
     showsRubricAddedPerClick int;
     siteLossLimitPerRubric NUMERIC(18,6);
     rtbMinRubricVisitsToShow int;
     showAdsToUsersWithoutInterests boolean;

BEGIN
......

DO
$do$
......
$do$;

PERFORM   "Id", "SiteId", "Domain", "JumpCost", "CPMCost", "PaymentModel",
5 as ComputedEpm, "ClickedCampaignId", "MainRubricId", "ShowSlider", 
"ShowGoods", "ShowTeaser", "BidLimitCoeff", "RtbActiveSiteStatByBannerId",
"ShowType", "MinAge" 

FROM mytable

ORDER BY "FromClick" DESC, "Similarity" DESC, "rn", random()
LIMIT 1;

END;

$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
COST 100
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
SECURITY INVOKER
VOLATILE;
```

As you see I used "PERFORM" to return results, but failed with error I explained.

Also, I used "Return query .. " and got same error.

"mytable" is temp table that I created in function.

How I can return this result?

Comment: You want `return query`. See the manual for details, it's all explained there: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING  Unrelated, but:  you should **really** avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers, they are much more trouble then they are worth it.

Comment: Why do you use `DO` anonymous block of code when you are already inside a function?

Comment: One of your problems is that you use the same names for the output parameters and the columns of the table you want to return. That leads to name collisions and surprising errors that are hard to debug. Avoid it by naming the output parameters differently, like `p_id` and `p_siteid`. And by the way, avoid upper case and mixed case names wherever possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe something like this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function(user_id integer)
  RETURNS TABLE(id integer, firstname character varying
                          , lastname  character varying) AS
$$
DECLARE
    ids character varying;
BEGIN
    ids := '';

    --Some code which build the ids string, not interesting for this issue

    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT users.id, users.firstname, users.lastname
    FROM public.users WHERE ids IN (' || ids || ')';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: I mentioned that I tried with RETURN QUERY EXECUTE!

Comment: Yes, but you didn't show the code. `RETURN QUERY` works fine in that case, maybe you made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Mistake was about schema, I didn't specified columns name with schema prefix. thanks.